# How do I save data on LocalStorage in Ruby on Rails 3.2.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, local-storage, session-variables

I'm trying to save a variable called `persistent_data`.

I usually use `session[:persistent_data]` or `cookies[:persistent_data]`, but I would like to use the localstorage instead.

How do I do that on Rails?

Comment: I know that LocalStorage is not related to Rails, but if there's a gem or something that allows us to store things directly to LocalStorage just like we do with cookies.

Answer (score 7):

Localstorage has nothing to do with rails. You do it the same way as with any other language:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("company_id", "1");
</script>

localStorage.getItem("company_id");
=> 1
```

You can use rails to dynamically set the item however:

```
<script>
localStorage.setItem("company_id", "<%= @company.id %>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

well this is quite simple and need to understand how local storage works.

You can do that directly or (and this is probably cleaner) use the setItem() and getItem() method:

```
localStorage.setItem('color','blue');
```

If you read out the color key, you will get back “blue”:

```
localStorage.getItem('color');`// output will be blue`
```

To remove the item, you can use the removeItem() method:

```
localStorage.removeItem('color');
```

annoying thing is when you have an array, it will not be stored the right way.

```
var car = {};
car.wheels = 4;
car.doors = 2;
car.sound = 'vroom';
car.name = 'Suzuki Mehran';
console.log( car );
localStorage.setItem( 'car', car );
console.log( localStorage.getItem( 'car' ) ); //output as `[object Object]`
```

but no need to worry we have a solution for that too..
You can work around this by using the native JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() methods:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'car', JSON.stringify(car) );
```

and you can get it back by simply

```
JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem( car ) );
```

hope you have not any confusion now !!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know localStorage has nothing to do with Rails, it is pure Javascript/HTML5 feature.

You can use the following in you application js in order to read or write data from the local storage:

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said local storage is Javascript/Html feature/solution but if wanting to learn how to integrate that with rails Ryan Bates has a railscast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/248-offline-apps-part-2, though you might need to watch part 1 to fully understand it.