# Rails 4: How to persist css changes, when toggling the background color of a list item?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and would like to toggle the background color of a list item when a user clicks it. How could I make the changes persist in Rails?
So when the user refreshes the page, the toggled background color persists.

Here is how I started, which worked, but didn't save the changes:

application.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".myitem").on("click", function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("changecolor");
    }); 
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <li class="myitem"><%= idea.description %></li>
<% end %>
```

.css file:

```
.changecolor {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

However, since I would like to make the changes persist, I tried AJAX, but now can't get it to work at all:

routes.rb

```
    resources :projects do
        resources :ideas do 
            put :toggle, on: :collection
        end
    end
```

Which created a route:

```
 toggle_project_ideas PUT    /projects/:project_id/ideas/toggle(.:format)   ideas#toggle
```

In the ideas_controller.rb I have

```
def toggle
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
  end
end
```

In index.html.erb

```
<% @ideas.each do |idea| %>
    <li class="myitem" id="<%= dom_id(idea) %>"><%= idea.description %></li>
<% end %>
```

In views/ideas/toggle.js.erb

```
$(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    $('<%= dom_id(idea) %>').toggleClass("red");
});
```

But the above doesn't work at all. How could I create a non-crud ajax call? Not sure where should I call remote: true? Should I have a totally different approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Local storage for storing the value of class when you change the class add that element's data to local storage as
localStorage.setItem("company_id", "1");
this will store the data at client side and for fetching the value from this use:
localStorage.getItem("company_id");
Please have a look at this:
[How do I save data on LocalStorage in Ruby on Rails 3.2.8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806198/how-do-i-save-data-on-localstorage-in-ruby-on-rails-3-2-8)